# PHP Email Title Display

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to figure out how I can change what shows up for my company when I send out `php` emails. Right now this shows up:

[image]

I don't want it to say newsletter, I want it to say my companies name. I don't have anything in my code that says newsletter, so I am unsure of why that is even displaying, unless it just naturally takes what comes before the @ in the email address. newsletter@companyname.com

What can I change in my code, so it reads my company name in the area I showed in the image, similar to what Amazon does, minus the .com.

```
$to = $newsletter_email;
        $subject = 'Thank you for subscribing to the Newsletter';
        $message = '
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title>Newsletter</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>
            </html>
                ';

                $from = "newsletter@companyname.com";
                $Bcc = "newsletter-notification@companyname.com";

                // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
                $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

                // Additional headers
                $headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Bcc: '.$Bcc. "\r\n";

                // Send the email
                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

[image]

Comment: [This comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#108368) will help make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$from = 'My Company <newsletter@companyname.com>';`

I think the problem is the way Gmail is displaying the *name* of the person when it's not specified.

Comment: That leaves an (Unknown Sender) name that comes up. See image I added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check what's in your `sendmail.ini` and `php.ini`:

### sendmail.ini

`force_sender=<email>`

### php.ini

`sendmail_from=<email>`

Comment: I don't have either of these? I don't have an ini file for this.

Comment: I guarantee you have a `php.ini` file. What type of server do you use?

Comment: You likely need to contact them and ask them to check this setting, or any other possible settings they may have that would control this value.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with it? `; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@localhost.com;

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i;

[Java]`

Comment: They appear to be commented out (start with a ";"), so it looks okay. I'm not sure this is the problem. When you changed the value and unknown came up, this would have overwritten that value. So it's probably something with the string formatting of the `$headers`. Try other names? Other emails?

Comment: What is wrong with my headers? I'm confused on what I should try to do.

Comment: Can you provide the output from `print_r($headers);`?